# json object not returning value in typeahead

Tags: json, object, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm trying to return a specific data from the json but it returns nothing.

I took the example from http://jsfiddle.net/Fresh/1hrk0qso/
It works perfectly when using the example url.

```
url: 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/twitter/typeahead.js/gh-pages/data/countries.json',
```

It also works when I do it from localhost

```
url: '../json/countries.json',
```

But, when I change the countries.json file to include multiple fields(see JSON below), it does not return anything.

JSON:

```
[
{"cities_id":"1","city":"Attignat","postal_code":"01340"},
{"cities_id":"2","city":"Beaupont","postal_code":"01270"},
{"cities_id":"3","city":"B\u00e9ny","postal_code":"01370"}
]
```

JS (modified only to return 'city' in replace for 'name' from the JSON file):

```
var countries = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('city'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    prefetch: {
        url: '../json/json_cities.json',
        filter: function (countries) {
            return $.map(countries, function (city) {
                return {
                    city: city
                };
            });
        }
    }
});

// Initialize the Bloodhound suggestion engine
countries.initialize();


    $('.typeahead_city').typeahead(null, {
        name: 'city',
        displayKey: 'city',
        source: countries.ttAdapter()
    });
```

I really do not understand because it is mostly the same as the example as well:
[How do I list objects for Typeahead.js and/or with the Bloodhound engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26227754/how-do-i-list-objects-for-typeahead-js-and-or-with-the-bloodhound-engine)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return the following properties in second parameter of typeahead method. If you want to return multiple items you have to use **display** property, instead of **displaykey**. While you could customize your suggestions with **suggestion** property.

> $('.typeahead_city').typeahead();

```
{   name: 'countries',
    display: function(item){ 
    return item.city+'–'+item.postal_code},
    source: dataSource.ttAdapter(),
    suggestion: function (data) {
            return '<div>' +data.city  + '–' + data.postal_code + '</div>'}    
}
```

Here is the working fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/geekowls/agrg3xhj/27/

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works with the 'local' search but not when trying to "prefetch{url: '../json/results_test.json'}"

Comment: No problem. It already works here in your fiddle. Here : http://jsfiddle.net/Fresh/1hrk0qso/ 
The json data in both examples is different ( Object Array  & String Array ). The above example is for handling Object Array. So what is your requirement? I will create a fiddle for that.

Comment: My mistake. In fact it works fine. From your jsfiddle, I simply added in replace to "local: jsondata" by "prefetch: {url: '../json/json_cities.json'}". But I may add a dynamic request because my json is 2MB

Comment: Okay. If it solved your problem don't forget to mark my answer. Thanks. :)

Comment: Sorry geekowls, if I may further annoy you... I want to store the value 'cities_id' from the json because I want to send it to my mysql database. I though modifying to return "item.cities_id" would be ok but suggestions turn to be the 'cities_id' as well. An idea ?

Comment: It's almost perfect. In your last example, when selecting, it shows for example "2-Beaupont–01270" but I want it to show "Beaupont–01270" and store/return "2" for mysql database that expects a unique Id. Thanks